# How to render flash message in Node.JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js, message

I am trying to display flash message without render, just redirect. It can possible if it is how ?

```
const session = require('express-session');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const urlencoded = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false})
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

const flash = require('connect-flash');
app.use(cookieParser('secret'));
app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboardSecrIncKey',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { secure: true, maxAge: 60000 }
}))

app.use(flash());

app.use('/test',urlencoded,(req,res,next)=>{
  if(req.body.name == ''){
    req.flash('info', 'Please Enter Your Name.');
    res.locals.message = req.flash();
    console.log(res.locals)
    res.redirect('back')
  }
  else{
    next()
  }
});
```

I am using handlebars view engine. And this is my test.handlebars file:

```
{{#if messages}}
 It is working
{{/if}}
```

But it won't display any text. If i use ***res.render('test', {...})*** it is working. But while i click refresh button browser send me alert(confirm the re-form submission etc.)

Comment: Do you understand how `req.flash()` works?  Whatever you flash has to be rendered into a future response by your code.  So, if you redirect to a page that doesn't have any code to show anything from the `.flash()`, then nothing will be displayed.

Comment: Thank you. Understood

Answer (score 2):

When you redirect, you tell your user's browser to display some other page. It is in that page that you would display your flash message, not in the page using `req.flash()` to create a flash message.